# Bootstrap datatables not responding to pagination

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, pagination, datatables

Good evening,

I have been working with Bootstrap datatables for a while, but have not seen this error.

So basically what is happening is that, I have initialized a bootstrap which actually works up until a point where the pagination not working.

To be clearer, The datatable shows the first 10 records, even when i select a higher number than 10 records, it still is showing 10 records, and saying (1-10 of 12 records),

Whenever i click next (or page 2), the results become blank even though there are 2 more records.

Note :The unseen records show up in the DOM when i view source, but it doesnt show when i search datatable etc.

Thank you.

Comment: As a starting point are there any js errors in the console?

Comment: Can you build a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) which reproduces the error?

Comment: Impossible to answer without any code, at least show how you initialize the datatable.

Comment: `code` <table class="table table-striped bootstrap-datatable datatable">

Comment: This is how i initialized the datatbale, as i said it works, but the pagination doesnt work